# Here I am getting trouble with last column. I want last column bg-color and borders up-to vertical scroll bar

Tags: css, html-table

Here I am getting trouble with last column. I want last column bg-color and borders up-to vertical scroll bar. And header text is overlapping.

Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/8JvZQ/[image]

[image]

Comment: Basically you want the table header to be visible all the time, correct?

Comment: yes table header should be visible.

Comment: for header, it should not scroll with content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here exactly like ur screenshot fixed the text overlaping. http://jsfiddle.net/8JvZQ/14/
hiding the row for fixing the overlapping text.

Comment: but here i am getting braking text in first column. http://jsfiddle.net/8JvZQ/17/

Comment: @ramanadham THANKS for giving some credit for my original fiddle. Both of you are disrespectful and ungracious users.

Answer (score 2):

**Floating header**

Added width: 100%; to .tableScrollBar table {}:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/8JvZQ/3/

**Note:** This is the straight-up solution to your problem. However, if you simply wish the effect of the table header always being visible. Then you can use jQuery to make the full  floatable on scroll. [Here is a demo](http://static.slackers.se/pages/javascript/jquery-floatheader/) of the floating header and [from here](http://static.slackers.se/pages/javascript/jquery-floatheader/) you can download it.

**Last row (CSS)**

This is css version of detecting the last row. However, it is not crossbrowser, since IE does recotnize :first-child but not :last-child :(

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/8JvZQ/4/

**Last row** (jQuery)

This is the jQuery version for detecting the last row. This is the ultimate solution!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/8JvZQ/9/

**Not full-width version**

This is being done by adding `display: inline-block;` to the global container.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/8JvZQ/10/

**Last column being full-width (just like your screenshot)**

Being done by adding `class="w100pre"` to phone column and also creating a new class: 
`.w100pre {width: 100%;}` that can be used globally on your site :)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/8JvZQ/11/

**NOTE:** I wasted about 2 hours on this question.

Comment: i dont want any space ofter the table content. plz fine the attachment screen which i want like that.

Comment: Define what space you mean. Everything looks okay in my fiddles. Actually they look better then your screenshot, maybe its in your browser locally? Can you provide a screenshot, of what your are seeing in my fiddles. Still, as you see it yourself, using this structure is not the optimal way. I strongly recommend of using the floating header, much more browser compatible and neater way.

Comment: i don't want selected red area of which i attached the screen shot. i want all the columns should be left like first screen shot.

Comment: So basically http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/8JvZQ/10/ there you go. 
NB! I added comments to css, of what I did and what you can do. 
Thought, still man..floating thead would be much more neat.

Comment: but table should expand up to browser edge. as my first screen shot attached.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/8JvZQ/11/ Now it should be exactly like your first screenshot.

Comment: i don't have that much reputations to chat with u. yes this is i want my table which i sent screen shot, but here last name is overlapping the phone column.

Comment: Your making it impossible on yourself. If you want to remove empty space, then the result will be this. If you would  As I said before, this is not the correct way of doing things. Your options are slim. Use one of the fiddles before.